# Spring Boot Data JPA - how to get data for the certain id

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, inner-join

I have two tables `Ticket` and `Flight`. One flight could have many tickets.

I want to show fields `departure_date`, `destination_date` from the table `Flight` and `name`, `surname` from the table `Ticket`. And show data only for the certain `flight_id`. I use findBy method.

[image]

Entity Flight

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "flight")
public class Flight {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer flight_id;

@Column(name = "departureDate")
private Date departureDate;

@Column(name = "destinationDate")
private Date destinationDate;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "flight")
@JsonManagedReference("flight")
private List<Ticket> tickets;
```

Entity Ticket

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ticket")
public class Ticket {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int ticket_id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "surname")
private String surname;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Flight.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "flight_id")
@JsonBackReference("flight")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private Flight flight;
```

I've created file FlightsTicketDto with certain fields:

```
public class FlightTicketDto {

private Integer flight_id;
private Date departureDate;
private Date destinationDate;
private String name;
private String surname;

public FlightTicketDto() {
}

public FlightTicketDto(Integer flight_id, Date departureDate, Date destinationDate, String name, String surname) {
    this.flight_id = flight_id;
    this.departureDate = departureDate;
    this.destinationDate = destinationDate;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
}
```

FlightTicketRepository with my Query

```
 public interface FlightTicketRepository extends JpaRepository<Ticket, Integer> {

 @Query("SELECT new pl.edu.wat.dto.FlightTicketDto(f.flight_id, f.departureDate, f.destinationDate, t.name, t.surname) "
        + "FROM Flight f INNER JOIN f.tickets t")
 List<FlightTicketDto> findByFlightId(Integer flight_id);
 }
```

FlightTicketController

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class FlightTicketController {

@Autowired
FlightTicketRepository flightTicketRepository;

@GetMapping("/mytickets/{flight_id}")
public List fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoin(@PathVariable Integer flight_id) {
    return flightTicketRepository.findByFlightId(flight_id);
}
```

Actually whatever `flight_id` (even not flight_id, but just another number) I write, I've got all my `flights`

For example I want to get result only for `flight_id = 431`, result you can see on the picture. What's wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
@Query("SELECT new pl.edu.wat.dto.FlightTicketDto(f.flight_id, f.departureDate, f.destinationDate, t.name, t.surname) "
        + "FROM Flight f INNER JOIN f.tickets t")
 List<FlightTicketDto> findByFlightId(Integer flight_id);
```

with

```
@Query("SELECT new pl.edu.wat.dto.FlightTicketDto(f.flight_id, f.departureDate, f.destinationDate, t.name, t.surname) "
            + "FROM Flight f INNER JOIN f.tickets t where f.flight_id = :flight_id")
     List<FlightTicketDto> findByFlightId(@Param("flight_id") Integer flight_id);
```