# How to show response of Spring Boot Data JPA Query in Angular 6

Tags: mysql, angular, spring-boot

It's continuous for my previous question [Spring Boot Data JPA - how to get data for the certain id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101081/spring-boot-data-jpa-how-to-get-data-for-the-certain-id)
In my Spring Boot application I have such a query:

```
public interface FlightTicketRepository extends JpaRepository<Ticket, Integer> {

@Query("SELECT new dto.FlightTicketDto(t.ticket_id, f.departureDate, f.destinationDate, t.name, t.surname) "
        + "FROM Flight f INNER JOIN f.tickets t where t.ticket_id = :ticket_id")
List<FlightTicketDto> findByTicketId(Integer ticket_id);}
```

And such a Controller

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class FlightTicketController {

@Autowired
FlightTicketRepository flightTicketRepository;

@GetMapping("/mytickets/{ticket_id}")
public List fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoin(@PathVariable Integer ticket_id) {
    return flightTicketRepository.findByTicketId(ticket_id);
}}
```

With my @Query everything is OK, I've got such a result:

[image]

I would like to show this result in my web application using Angular 6

FlightTicket.ts

```
export class FlightTicket {
 ticket_id: number;
 departureDate: Date;
 destinationDate: Date;
 name: string;
 surname: string;
}
```

FlightTicketService.ts

```
 export class FlightTicketService {

 private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/mytickets';

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
 }

 fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoin(ticket_id: number): Observable<FlightTicket> {
 return this.http.get<FlightTicket>(`${this.baseUrl}/${ticket_id}`);
 }
```

mytickets-list.component.html -   here I want to show my query response

```
<div *ngIf="flightTicket">
<label>Destination date: </label> {{ flightTicket.destinationDate }}<br/>
<label>Departure date: </label> {{ flightTicket.departureDate }}<br/>
<label>Name: </label> {{ flightTicket.name }}<br/>
<label>Surname: </label> {{ flightTicket.surname }}<br/>
<label>id: </label> {{ flightTicket.ticket_id }}<br/>
```

myticketslist-component.ts

```
export class MyticketsListComponent implements OnInit {

 flightTicket: FlightTicket = new FlightTicket( );
 flightTickets: Observable<FlightTicket[]>;
 ticket_id: number;

 constructor(private flightTicketService: FlightTicketService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
 this.ticket_id = 443;
 this.reloadData();
 }

reloadData() {
this.flightTicketService.fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoin(this.ticket_id).
subscribe((response) => {
  this.flightTicket = response;
});}}
```

Here is the result. Empty. What's wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that request was sent with success? 
To me subscribe was not invoked at all. And it displays empty label because of 
`flightTicket: FlightTicket = new FlightTicket( );` So ngIf='flightTicket' is true.

Comment: In other classes of my application I have the same and it's OK. Here maybe problem is that I don't have such a table `flightTicket` in my database. So should I create a constructor in FlightTicket.ts and put some parameters here `=new FlightTicket() `? But problem is that I want to get parameters from my database, but not by default.

Comment: Problem is not with backend as you already noticed backend return correct result. Check console in the browser and verify that response status and body is okay.

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: [Network request details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/request_details) maybe this will help you

Comment: why dont you debug your  `.subscribe()` callback, to see if the control is comes inside it or not ?  you can check this blog to understand how to debug code from chrome dev tools,https://blog.angularjs.org/2012/07/introducing-angularjs-batarang.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've debugged using `Augury` and found out that my json response is like an Array, not like an Object (like it should be)

So I changed in my backend:

```
@GetMapping("/mytickets/{ticket_id}")
public ResponseEntity<FlightTicketDto> fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoin(@PathVariable("ticket_id") Integer ticket_id) {
    FlightTicketDto flight = flightTicketRepository.findByTicketId(ticket_id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(flight, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

and here:

```
@Query("SELECT new dto.FlightTicketDto(t.ticket_id, f.departureDate, f.destinationDate, t.name, t.surname) "
        + "FROM Flight f INNER JOIN f.tickets t where t.ticket_id = :ticket_id")
FlightTicketDto findByTicketId(Integer ticket_id);
```